# incompatible types: byte[] cannot be converted to byte

Tags: java, byte, rsa

Im currently trying to encrypt user input data using RSA ( i know its not the best way but its for an assignment and i need to do it this way) i have it encrypting and decrypting small strings of data but am now trying to move on to any length of data by splitting the string at each word, but when i try to encrypt the data this way i get an error saying "incompatible types: byte[] cannot be converted to byte"

I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it. any help would be great so even an idea on how to go about this differently

```
final String originalText = "New Class NewClass NewClass NewClass ";
        String[] splited = originalText.split("\\s+");

        ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;

        // Encrypt the string using the public key
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE));
        final PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) inputStream.readObject();
        final byte[] cipherText = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < splited.length; i++) {
            LINE ERROR APPEARS ON
            cipherText[i] = encrypt(splited[i], publicKey);
            System.out.println(cipherText[i]);

        }
```

Comment: probably: `encrypt()` return `byte[]` not `byte`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call `encrypt` you get Byte array, so your `cipherText` can be `byte[][] cipherText`, and then to see it just call `System.out.println(new String(cipherText[i]));`

**EDIT** `NPE` is raised because you didn't initialized your `cipherText` array. Please try the following:

```
byte[][] cipherText = new byte[splited.length][];
```

Comment: That works great now im getting a nullpointer exception on the same line when i run it

Comment: @m4773rz can you post stacktrace? BTW, inside your loop you always assign result to the `0` element, I think it's a typo

Comment: Do you know how to post a stacktrace form Netbeans i had a quick google there and couldn't see how, yes i saw that my self and edited it.

Comment: @m4773rz Never worked with Netbeans, but you should be able to copy-paste from console

Comment: New
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at itteration1.EncryptionClasses.RSA.main(RSA.java:175)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: @m4773rz can you please say what's on the line `RSA.java:175`?

Comment: Yup its the   cipherText[i] = encrypt(splited[i], publicKey); line in the middle of the for loop